# Android Studio see currently open file in project structure

Tags: android

Lets say I have a file open in a large project. How do you see the corresponding file in the project structure view on the left side while the file is open on the right ?

Comment: There's a `Scroll from Source` button above the project structure, looks like an X in a circle. That button will focus you on the file you're currently looking at (on the right-side) in the project structure (on the left-side)

Answer (score 92):

You can configure your IDE to **automatically select the file when you access** it. Just access the option: ***"Show Options Menu"*** and activate the item ***"Always Select Opened file"***.
See image below. Android Studio version: 4.0.1

[image: Automatic activation]

**::EDIT::**

If you do not want this behavior to be automatic but only in some files, disable the flagged option and use the action as shown in the image below:

[image: Manual activation]

Comment: This option should be selected by default. Thanks!

Comment: That's nice, but what if I want to do it once, and not always? Is there a way to do it instead of enabling this option and disabling it after the file has been selected?

Comment: @MateusFelipe, yes, you can. I edited the answer and added this option.

Comment: Thanks, @WedsonQuintanilhadaSilva. This options does not appear in my Android Studio. Instead, it gives the option to "Expand All" in the right of the "Collapse All" that is in your image.

Comment: still wander sometimes who develops UIs like this? this is android studion we are talking about ... the icons appear only if the mouse is over the left window

Answer (score 45):

It's `Scroll from Source` that you want. It's the one the red arrow is pointing to in the following image:

[image: Scroll from Source button screenshot]

Also, there's an `Autoscroll from Source` (as well as `Autoscroll to Source`) on the settings icon, if you are interested. If selected, instead of having to press the `Scroll from Source` button, the active file gets shown automatically in the project structure.

Comment: The "Autoscroll from Source" was changed to "Always Select Opened File" (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/63525744/624814 below).  Some companies just can't resist changing things that work.

Answer (score 14):

Push ALT+F1.

In the popup you can select where do you want to show the file.

To show in the project structure select "1. Project View" → "Project".

Comment: For mac its option + f1

Answer (score 0):

You can only open the file from the left project structure and as on right,
if you are on large project you need to expand the project structure and go through the package and expand folder structure. You will get the open file name as selected with dark gray back gound if the Editer is on Dracula mode and blue if in intellij.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is searching for `Select File in Project View` on Keymap session and putting the desired hotkey.